# getMaxAmplitude from MediaRecorder Android NDK class in FireMonkey application

Tags: android, delphi, android-ndk, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I want to use `getMaxAmplitude` function from `MediaRecorder` Android NDK class in my FireMonkey application. Documentation recommends to use `TAudioCaptureDevice` for audio recording in applications but it doesn't provide such functionality. I was thinking to write class helper for `TAndroidAudioCaptureDevice` but it is in `implementation` section of the `FMX.Media.Android` unit and can't be accessed from another unit.

The question is why `TAudioCaptureDevice` doesn't provide the full functionality of NDK?

And why `TAndroidAudioCaptureDevice` is in implementation section so I can't extended it with my routines?

So it seems like I have to write my own class for audio recording.

Comment: 'The question is why TAudioCaptureDevice doesn't provide the full functionality of NDK?' - Because it seeks to serve as a lowest common denominator interface for 'audio capture devices' regardless of the platform. Was that really your question?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. I understand that TAudioCaptureDevice should contain the common functionality for all platforms but why TAndroidAudioCaptureDevice is in implementation section and I can't write class helper for it?

Comment: You are not the first person to complain about that coding style in the FMX source, but anyone here (including myself) can only speculate as to the reason. Perhaps it's to make it easier to do same-version updates (DCU compatibility)? Or, perhaps someone at Embarcadero genuinely believes in a '90s VB-style 'black box' approach? Or, perhaps the rushed nature of FMX releases means they want to make it easier to muck around with the FMX API release to release? Etc.

Comment: Thank you Chris for you explanation.